# Return value object in FastAPI

Tags: python, fastapi

I'd like to work with this Python class as a value object that serialises to/from `str`, with FastAPI:

```py
class KsuidPrefixed:
    """Class with two fields: a Ksuid and the prefix. Uses the PREFIX_SEPARATOR to separate the prefix from the Ksuid. Also overrides __str__ etc, to make it behave like a string"""

    def __init__(self, prefix: str, ksuid: Ksuid):
        self.prefix = prefix
        self.ksuid = ksuid

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.prefix}{PREFIX_SEPARATOR}{str(self.ksuid)}"

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return str(self)

    def __eq__(self, other: object) -> bool:
        assert isinstance(other, self.__class__)
        return self.prefix == other.prefix and self.ksuid == other.ksuid

    def __lt__(self, other: object) -> bool:
        assert isinstance(other, self.__class__)
        return self.ksuid < other.ksuid

    def __hash__(self) -> int:
        return hash(self.ksuid)
```

However, if I simply return a dict with this id in it:

```py
intent_id = KsuidSegment("i")
@api.get("/{id}")
def read(id: Annotated[KsuidPrefixed, Depends(intent_id)]):
    results = {"intent_id": id} # str(id) would work
    return results
```

I'd get this error:

```py
>   ???
E   UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x83 in position 3: invalid start byte
```

Can I make FastAPI understand I want to treat KsuidPrefixed as a proper value object, and have it call `__str__` on it?

Comment: shouldn't `class KsuidPrefixed:` be `class KsuidPrefixed(BaseModel):` ? where BaseModel come from pydantic ?

Comment: Well, if I do: "RuntimeError: no validator found for <class 'libsvc.ksuid.ksuid.Ksuid'>, see `arbitrary_types_allowed` in Config" and then if that's added "Invalid args for response field! Hint: check that <class 'libsvc.ksuid.ksuid.Ksuid'> is a valid Pydantic field type."

Comment: I just want to adjust how from string and to string serialisation works!